# HttpClient PostAsync List<string> instead of file.csv

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am attempting to post content to a vendor. The data uploads when I save my data to a .csv then reference the file. What I would prefer to do is skip saving the file to disk and just upload the data. I can't seem to figure out how to serialize the data correctly.

Here is the data:

```
csv.Add(string.Join(",", "sara1234", "Ancient World Studies-1201A1-01"));
csv.Add(string.Join(",", "jazzy4567", "Ancient World Studies-1201A1-01"));
```

Here is the upload:

```
protected async Task<bool> RunAsync(string baseAddress, IEnumerable<string> file, string passkey)
{
    byte[] csvBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Projects\\AutomationServiceFiles\\DataMig_Test\\Drop\\Hapara\\HaparaStudent.csv");
    var csvContent = new ByteArrayContent(csvBytes);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            content.Add(new StringContent(passkey), "passkey");
            content.Add(csvContent, "uploadFile", "student.csv");

            var response = await client.PostAsync(baseAddress, content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string returnedContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }                
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have tried what's shown below (instead of the file from disk). I get a 200 success message back, but data does not load. Specifically, the first method returns a message that the students were not found (this is good because I know the data was evaluated), the second returns no message at all.

```
string jsonFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(file);
HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(jsonFile, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
content.Add(contentPost, "uploadFile", "student.csv");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does your vendor expect to receive the data? as a `byte[]`?

Comment: I would assume that when the file is picked up as a file by HttpClient that it is sending it as a byte[], but I'm not certain. They are expecting us to use cURL, which we would rather not do.

Comment: I understand that you rather not, but if you don't conform to the type they're expecting, you wont see the data being uploaded.

Comment: It picks up the file and accepts the data via HttpClient if I reference a .csv file on disk. My assumption is that data is a byte array. From what I can see at the vendors end, is the jSON is missing the line feeds. Could I do this using a memory stream?

Answer (score 0):

You could just build the CSV string and pass it to a new instance of StringContent instead of using ByteArrayContent.